# Rails 4 - Displaying items from database tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have the following models and their associations:

#### #models

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :order_items
    has_many :items, :through => :order_items
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, :order_items, :allow_destroy => true
end
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :order_items
    has_many :orders, :through => :order_items
end
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :order
end
```

I want to display the `item.name`, `order_item.quantity` and `order_item.price` in one table as attempted below:

```
  <tbody>
    <% @order.items.each do |item| %> <<<<<<<< need this to call item.name
      <% @order.order_items.each do |order_item| %> <<<<<<< need this to call the other fields
        <tr>
          <td><%= item.name %></td>
          <td><%= order_item.quantity %></td>
          <td><%= order_item.price %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

the above works in calling the specific field but how it is written will not do because inner loop needs to finish before outer and hence we don't get what we need.

#### #Tables snippets

```
create_table "items", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.integer  "stock"
    t.string   "location"
    t.decimal  "discount"
    t.boolean  "status"
  end
  create_table "order_items", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "item_id"
    t.integer  "order_id"
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.decimal  "price"
  end
  create_table "orders", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "code"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.text     "memo"
    t.boolean  "status"
    t.integer  "client_id"
    t.decimal  "sub_total"
  end
```

#### #orders form

```
<%= compact_form_for(@order) do |f| %>
 <%= f.association :client, collection: Client.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, prompt: "Client Name", required: true %>

 <%= f.simple_fields_for :items do |o| %>
  <%= o.input :name, collection: Product.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :id %>
  <%= o.input :quantity %>
 <% end %>

 <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: i cant see neither the quantity attribute nor the price attribute, can you update your question?

Comment: @jandresrodriguez added the relevant tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to use the [`.delegate`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) method with the `OrderItem` model, like this:

```
#app/models/order_item.rb
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :order
    delegate :name, to: :item #-> allows you to call @order_item.name 
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
<tbody>
    <% @order.order_items.each do |item| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= item.name %></td>
          <td><%= item.quantity %></td>
          <td><%= item.price %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
</tbody>
```

---

**Fix**

A **much** better way to make this work will be to use the following model names:

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items
    has_many :orders, :through => :items
end

#app/models/order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items
    has_many :products, :through => :items
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, :allow_destroy => true
end

#app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :order
    delegate :name, to: :product #-> allows you to call @item.name 
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
<tbody>
    <% @order.items.each do |item| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= item.name %></td>
          <td><%= item.quantity %></td>
          <td><%= item.price %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: for the order model in your answer, did you mean to write `accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, :products, :allow_destroy => true` instead of `accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, :order_items, :allow_destroy => true`

Comment: Sorry, it should be :products only! Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: Using the "better way" approach, the items table would not update when submitting a nested form. 

`<%= f.simple_fields_for :items do |o| %>`
`<%= o.input :name, collection: Product.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :id %>`
`<%= o.input :quantity %>`
`<% end %>` under the orders new form

Comment: If you update your Q with the form, I'll take a look at it for you if you want/